# Making a Ruby string immutable

Tags: ruby, string

Need to make certain Ruby strings in my program to be immutable. What is the best solution?  Writing a wrapper over `String` class?

The `freeze` method won't work for me. I see that `freeze` won't allow you to unfreeze the object.

Following is my situation: I have a class that passes a string to a callback. This string happens to be an instance variable of the class and can be potentially large. I don't want the callback to modify it, but still allow the class to modify it at will.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to make the String immutable, but rather to restrict the ability to mutate it.

Comment: @zetetic: Agree. Thats precisely what I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Following is my situation: I have a class that passes a string to a
>   callback.

Would passing a copy of the string to the callback work?

> This string happens to be an instance variable of the class
>   and can be potentially large. I don't want the callback to modify it,
>   but still allow the class to modify it at will.

If you're worried about the size of the string, then using String#dup will help. It'll create a new object, with a distinct `object_id`, but the contents of the string won't be copied, unless the new string (or the original) gets modified. This is called "copy on write", and is described in [Seeing double: how Ruby shares string values](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/1/18/seeing-double-how-ruby-shares-string-values).

Comment: Using `dup` sounds perfect to me. I wouldn't want to modify the base `String` class because it will probably buy trouble for later debugging.

Comment: Thanks. String#dup is a nice fit for the above scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Call `#freeze` on the String. See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-freeze

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work in my case. Please see the edit to my original post.

Comment: +1 to this answer because it is always possible to #dup frozen string and the result would be a mutable copy.