# Read-only arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When I need to return immutable collection from my class in C# or Java I return it as IEnumerable interface. What is the standard way for this in Ruby? Clone? Freeze?

Comment: Why must it be immutable? You can't enforce it. Someone can always dig in and play with the contents.

Comment: Because it will make object's internal state inconsistent. Some settings that could only be modified with specific methods.

Comment: @synapse If you freeze it, then *you* won't be able to modify it either.

Comment: This is not something you typically do in Ruby (or any dynamic language). If you provided more details on what you want to accomplish, someone can show you the idiomatic Ruby way.

Comment: Think of something like the database index (actually, that's exactly what I'm implementing for a job interview). You set the columns to be indexed on creation but obviously you need to have a way to tell consumers what they are. I think it's a common case with settings-like properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a Ruby string immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148276/making-a-ruby-string-immutable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a `RuntimeError` raised if modification is attempted, then use `freeze()`.  If you only want to prevent the caller from modifying *your* data, then `clone()` is a good choice.

Keep in mind that [freeze() might not work like you expect](http://m.onkey.org/ruby-i-don-t-like-3-object-freeze).

Personally, I've never had need for `freeze()`, but `clone()` is often useful.

Comment: Note that Ruby before 1.9 raises a TypeError instead of a RuntimeError. Also +1 for mentioning the gotchas of `freeze`.

Comment: +1 for `dup` and `clone`, nice solution to this problem. Regarding that blog post, `freeze` does exactly what it says it does. `freeze` is not `const`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why `freeze()` might not work 'like you expect'? Your link gives me "Application Error: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served."

Comment: @DavidMoles Honestly, I don't remember.  Hopefully that page will come back.  I *think* the gist was that freeze isn't broken or anything, but that it's common to misunderstand exactly what it does or what its implications are.  It went into specifics that I don't recall, but are surely documented elsewhere.

Comment: Looking at other related questions, maybe something to do with freezing objects vs freezing variables/references? Seems like a lot of newbies seem to think `foo = bar; foo.freeze; foo = baz` should fail.